# Report Viewer Configuration Error in IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis, reportviewer, windows-server-2019

I have my report viewer working perfectly on windows server 2012 (IIS 7) but when i moved the site to window server 2019 (IIS 10) it start showing the web.config error about config error. I went through related question here but most talk about IIS 7 and later solutions which seems not working despite trying solution here and the error message and my config are the same. error below

> Report Viewer Configuration Error
> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

Answer (score 0):

add below code to <system.web> section:

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <!-- Add this line -->
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</httpHandlers>
```

and this one under "system.webServer" section:

```
  <handlers>
    <!-- Add these lines -->
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</handlers>
```

if still not work try to change the app pool from Integrated to Classic.

Comment: thanks, but i have done all those and error still persists

Answer (score 0):

> Found my problem. In my case I was using an external provider; but the same issue may occur for those running IIS under their own control.
> WebHosting Providers may not allow applications to modify all IIS Settings.
> So the web.config items to register axd were being ignored.
> In my case - from the WebHosting Support team

No, it’s saying that ModSecurity has flagged calls to those file extensions as a security risk.
You can add the rule ID (920440) to the list titled “Security rule IDs” under the “Switch off security rules” heading in the Web Application Firewall settings.
This will stop this rule from triggering on this site